# ¿Como mostrar el ultimo id después de insertar?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

Contexto: Estoy trabajando con asp.net y sql server. "NuevoLibro.aspx.cs" es donde estoy trabajando para poder agregar un nuevo libro y lo que deseo poder mostrar es que cuando agregue ese nuevo libro le muestre el código(su ID) en el cual quedo agregado, teniendo en cuenta que los libros se están agregando en un procedimiento almacenado con un MAX()+1

Mi Procedimiento almacenado

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LI_Agregar_Ejemplar_JP]
     @Titulo VARCHAR(100),
     @Edi NUMERIC(18),
     @Autor VARCHAR(60),
     @Ubi VARCHAR(6),
     @numero int output
AS
BEGIN


 INSERT INTO EJEMPLAR (codlib,TITLIB,EDILIB,AUTLIB,UBILIB,ULTLEC,DISPON,FECPRE,FECDEV)
 SELECT MAX(codlib)+1,@Titulo,@Edi,@Autor,@Ubi,0,1,0,0 FROM EJEMPLAR
 SELECT @numero = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Aun no entiendo como utilizar el Scope_Identity pero esta agregado igualmente al procedimiento

Mi clase AgregarLibro:

```
 protected void AgregarLibro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            if (txttitulo.Text != " " || txteditorial.Text != " " || txtautor.Text != " " || txtubicacion.Text != " ")
            {
                Titulo = txttitulo.Text;
                Editorial = txteditorial.Text;
                Autor = txtautor.Text;
                Ubi = txtubicacion.Text;
                PrepararAcceso.AgregarEjemplar(Titulo, Editorial, Autor, Ubi, CadenaConexion);
                Response.Write("<script >alert('Libro ingresado Correctamente');location.href = 'Libros.aspx';</script>");
                 
            }
```

Lo que quiero tratar de hacer es mostrar en ese  por ejemplo:
("alert('Libro "+ ID +"ingresado Correctamente') donde ID sea el numero en donde se alojo ese libro que en este caso debería ser el ultimo.
O lo otro es mostrar en un titulo el ID en donde se alojara ese libro

Ayuda por favor!

Comment: Para mantener una secuencia, no se usa MAX(columna) al insertar, pues eso va a tener líos cuando haya concurrencia y va a fallar. Revisa la respuesta que te dan

Answer (score 1):

El `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` así como la variable `@@IDENTITY` devuelve el último valor de identidad insertado en una columna de identidad.

En tu caso parece que la columna `codlib` no tiene activada esta característica, por lo que no es autonumérico y por lo tanto `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` no devuelve nada.

Para devolver el dato que estás buscando es tan sencillo como devolver el valor insertado:

```
SET @numero = (SELECT MAX(codlib)+1 FROM EJEMPLAR)

INSERT INTO EJEMPLAR (codlib,TITLIB,EDILIB,AUTLIB,UBILIB,ULTLEC,DISPON,FECPRE,FECDEV)
SELECT @numero,@Titulo,@Edi,@Autor,@Ubi,0,1,0,0

SELECT @numero
```